# Proof of $ \sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (x_n+y_n) \le\sup x_n+\sup y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

For sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ we define: $\sup_{n\in \Bbb N}  a_n=\{a_{n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$: prove that for each pair of sequences $(x_{n})_{n\in \Bbb N}, (y_{n})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ which are bounded from above 
$$
\sup_{n\in \Bbb N} (x_n+y_n) \le \sup  x_n+\sup y_n
$$
and point out such pair of sequences, for which presented inequality is "$<$".

My attempt: let $a=\sup x_n$, and $b=\sup y_n$ and define the *addition sequences* as: 
$(a_n)+(b_n):=(a_n+b_n)$

1. When quantity of elements $(a_n)$ different from $(y_n)$:

   - $\sup(x_n+y_n)=\max\{a,b\},\text{ and }\sup x_n+\sup y_n=a+b$, thus
     $\max\{a,b\}\le a+b$ for all $a,b$.
2. When quantity of elements $(a_n)$ equals $(y_n)$:

   - $\sup(x_n+y_n)=a+b=\sup x_n+\sup y_n$

Does it makes sense?

Comment: Do you mean ''...we define $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a_n = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{a_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by ''When quantity of elements $(a_n)$ different from $(y_n)$:'' what is $(a_n)$?

Comment: Hmm.. . You' re right. Now, I realised that it is nonsense, because $x_n$ and $y_n$ are infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by definition supremum is the least upper bound.

Therefore it suffices to show that, $$ (x_n+y_n) \le \sup_{n\in \Bbb N}x_n+\sup_{n\in \Bbb N}  y_n$$ because that makes $$\sup  x_n+ \sup y_n$$ an upper bound for  $\{ (x_n+y_n)\}$, $n\in \Bbb N$

Since $$ x_n \le \sup_{n\in \Bbb N} \{x_n\}$$ and  $$ y_n \le \sup_{n\in \Bbb N} \{y_n\}$$ We get $$x_n+y_n \le \sup \{x_n\} +\sup \{y_n\}$$

Thus the least upper bound is less than or equal to this  particular upper bound.

Comment: This method is actually better than the one I presented since we don't know beforehand that $\sup(x_n+y_n)$ is bounded from above and this shows it

Comment: @OlofRubin Thanks for your attention and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start on how one could proceed with proving this:
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be some arbitrary positive number. Pick $N$ such that 
$$\sup(x_n+y_n)-\varepsilon<x_N+y_N$$

(why can we find such an $N$?). What upper bound can you place on the right-hand side?

---

Edit: This is only applicable if we beforehand know that $\sup(x_n+y_n)$ is finite.

Comment: $sup(x_n+y_n)-\varepsilon<x_N+y_N < sup \ x_n + sup \ y_n$?

Comment: precisely so what does this imply?

Comment: @matematiccc Since $sup(x_n+y_n)-ε<sup x_n + sup y_n$ for ALL $ε>0$, we must have $sup(x_n+y_n) \leq sup x_n + sup y_n$

Comment: yes! I thought that this answer is too trivial. Now, I'm thinking why such N exists.

Comment: You should look at the other answer this method (which is very powerful) only works if we beforehand know that $\sup (x_n+y_n)$ is bounded but we did not show it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_n$ and $b=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}y_n$. Then, for every $n$,
$$
x_n\le a,\qquad y_n\le b
$$
and therefore $x_n+y_n\le a+b$, giving
$$
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(x_n+y_n)\le a+b
$$
because the supremum is at most equal to any upper bound.

It's generally false that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(x_n+y_n)=\max\{a,b\}$. Take two constant sequences $x_n=1$ and $y_n=2$. Then $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=3\ne\max\{1,2\}$.

How do we find two sequences where the strict inequality holds?

Take $x_n=1$ when $n$ is even and $x_n=-1$ if $n$ is odd. Define $y_n=-x_n$.